# CSS - How should I center a div body using transform when I have a fixed div header?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
/*header*/
<div id="headerDiv">
    /*.......*/
</div>

/*body*/
<div class="calendar">
    /*.......*/
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*header*/
#headerDiv{
position: fixed;
height:12%;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
text-align: center;
}

/*body*/
.calendar{
text-align:center;
float:left;
background-color:blue
height:80%;
width:90%;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

When I try to use `position:absolute` with `position:fixed` the body runs over the header. I want the div in the body to be centered both horizontally and vertically while being positioned below the header.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Can you please show us a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Isn't the div already centered both horizontally and vertically https://jsfiddle.net/g6camng3/ ?

Answer (score 0):

using translate gives unexpected result in Internet Explorer, try this

```
.calendar{
text-align:center;
background-color:blue
height:80%;
width:90%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
padding-top:12%;
}
```